# How do I declare a function pointer to a method in Go

Tags: go

I am trying to create function pointer to a function that has a method receiver. However, I can't figure out how to get it to work (if it is possible)?

Essentially, I have the following:

```
type Foo struct {...}
func (T Foo) Bar bool {
   ... 
}

type BarFunc (Foo) func() bool // Does not work.
```

The last line of the code gives the error

```
syntax error: unexpected func, expecting semicolon or newline
```

Comment: So you basically want to have a type that can only refer to functions that are bound to a type?

Comment: `type BarFunc func(Foo) bool` is equivalent. Please tell us what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to create a function pointer to a method, you have two ways. The first is essentially turning a method with one argument into a function with two:

```
type Summable int

func (s Summable) Add(n int) int {
    return s+n
}

var f func(s Summable, n int) int = (Summable).Add

// ...
fmt.Println(f(1, 2))
```

The second way will "bind" the value of `s` (at the time of evaluation) to the `Summable` receiver method `Add`, and then assign it to the variable `f`:

```
s := Summable(1)
var f func(n int) int = s.Add
fmt.Println(f(2))
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/ctovxsFV2z.

Any changes to `s` after `f` is assigned will have no affect on the result: https://play.golang.org/p/UhPdYW5wUOP

Answer (score 2):

And for an example more familiar to those of us used to a `typedef` in C for function pointers:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type DyadicMath func (int, int) int  // your function pointer type

func doAdd(one int, two int) (ret int) {
    ret = one + two;
    return
}

func Work(input []int, addthis int, workfunc DyadicMath) {
    for _, val := range input {
        fmt.Println("--> ",workfunc(val, addthis))
    }
}

func main() {
    stuff := []int{ 1,2,3,4,5 }
    Work(stuff,10,doAdd)

    doMult := func (one int, two int) (ret int) {
        ret = one * two;
        return
    }   
    Work(stuff,10,doMult)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/G5xzJXLexc

Answer (score 0):

I am very likely off-target (just started on Golang) but what if you create a pointer then examine type:

```
pfun := Bar 
fmt.Println("type of pfun is:", reflect.TypeOf(pfun))
```

then it seems that you can declare the type of pointer correctly:
https://play.golang.org/p/SV8W0J9JDuQ